# Unsuccessful Encryption

Tags: root-access, encryption

I began encrypting my Xperia Z3 and as soon as the process started, the phone turned off and I was greeted with the following screen:

[image]

The phone was rooted beforehand and I still have access to a custom recovery. Is there anything I can do to restore all of my apps? The phone is still reading that space is being taken up on the internal Memory.

Comment: Boot into recovery, and try restoring the data with ADB.